# Django bus timetable query - sum durations and add to a departure time

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I've written some Django models and loaded some data for a bus timetable system but am having trouble with writing a query. Here are the models:

```
class VehicleJourney(models.Model):
    vehicle_journey = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    journey_pattern = models.ForeignKey('JourneyPattern')
    departure_time = models.TimeField()

class TimingLink(models.Model):
    timing_link = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    journey_pattern = models.ForeignKey('JourneyPattern')
    from_seq_no = models.IntegerField()
    from_stop = models.ForeignKey('Stop', related_name='+')
    to_seq_no = models.IntegerField()
    to_stop = models.ForeignKey('Stop', related_name='+')
    runtime = models.IntegerField()

class Stop(models.Model):
    stop_point = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    common_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class JourneyPattern(models.Model):
    journey_pattern = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    direction = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    service = models.ForeignKey('Service')

class Service(models.Model):
   service_code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
   registered_operator_ref = models.ForeignKey('Operator')
   mode = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   start_date = models.DateField()
   end_date = models.DateField()
   origin = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   destination = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

The query takes an input of from_stop, to_stop and an arrival time to find the 3 next buses departing from from_stop,and arriving at to_stop by arrival_time.

I want to return the TimingLinks between from_stop and to_stop, with each runtime successively added to VehicleJourney.departure_time giving departure times for each stop.

Any insights on how I could best approach this?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your models? Also, the ForeignKeys shouldn't be in quotes, and I _believe_ that any FK's should be defined above the model that references it (i.e. Stop should be above TimingLink; VehicleJourney and TimingLink should be above JourneyPattern)

Comment: I've added more of the models, there are some more e.g. Operator, but don't think they're relevant. ForeignKeys can be in quotes according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Comment: Apologies, I'd never seen ForeignKeys in quotes before. You're right.